# Mortgage calculator math error

Tags: python, math, calculator

This program *runs* fine, but the monthly payment it returns is totally off. For a principal amount of $400,000, interest rate of 11%, and a 10-year payment period, it returns the monthly payment of $44000.16. I googled the equation (algorithm?) for mortgage payments and put it in, not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

def mortgage(principal, interest, n):
    payment = principal*((interest*(1+interest)**n) / ((1+interest)**n-1))
    return payment

principal = float(input("What is the amount of the loan you are taking out? $"))
interest = float(input("What is the interest rate? (%) ")) / 100
n = float(input("How many years? ")) * 12
print
print "Your monthly payment would be", locale.currency(mortgage(principal, interest, n))
```

Comment: Initial guess without looking at the code: there's a problem with the equation's parentheses and/or order of operations.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator#Monthly_payment_formula

Comment: Can you tell us where exactly you found the equation you're trying to use, and what the correct answer should be?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I googled "how to calculate a mortgage" and got it from http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Mortgage-Payments and then confirmed it on another site. The correct answer is supposed to be $5,510. I'm very confused, because it seems as though it must be an error in the order of operations but I can't pick anything out.  .... other site was https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/finance/mortgage/faq/calculate-monthly-mortgage-payment/

Comment: Are you sure your banker hasn't hacked your computer to trick you into paying $44000.16/month?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in your interest rate used. You request the annual interest rate and never convert to a monthly interest rate.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator#Monthly_payment_formula:

> r - the **monthly** interest rate, expressed as a decimal, not a
>   percentage. Since the quoted yearly percentage rate is not a
>   compounded rate, the monthly percentage rate is simply the yearly
>   percentage rate divided by 12; dividing the monthly percentage rate by
>   100 gives r, the monthly rate expressed as a decimal.

I just tried this on my computer and dividing the interest rate by 12 calculated $5510/month which agrees with other mortgage calculators.

Comment: Yep! Fixed it by dividing `interest` by 12. Thank you.