# C++ Mortgage Calculator Incorrect Formula

Tags: c++, math

I am struggling with this C++ program on getting the correct amount for monthly payment. There is something that I am doing wrong with the formula I believe that I can't quite figure out and it is messing up the output for total pay back as well. I need some help figuring it out. I added what I have so far for my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void mortgage::Mortgage() { // class object
    double loanAmount = 0;
    double annualInterestRate = 0;
    double totalYearsToRepay = 0;

  cout << "Enter the amount of the loan:";
  cin >> loanAmount;
  cout << "Enter annual interest rate in decimal term (example 0.075):";
  cin >> annualInterestRate;
  cout << "Enter the length of the loan in years:";
  cin >> totalYearsToRepay;

 cout << "Loan Amount: $" << fixed << loanAmount << endl;
 cout << "Annual Interest Rate: $" << fixed << annualInterestRate << endl;
 cout << "Total Years to Repay: $" << fixed << totalYearsToRepay << endl;

// Find monthly interest rate.
monthlyInterestRate=annualInterestRate /12;

// Find the total # of payments needed.
numberOfPayments = totalYearsToRepay* 12;

// Find power Factor.
 powerFactor = pow(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfPayments);

// Find the monthly payment.
monthlyPayment= (loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate)/(1-pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, totalYearsToRepay));

cout << "Monthly Payment: $" << fixed << annualInterestRate << endl;

    // Find the total pay back
    totalPayBack = (monthlyPayment) * (numberOfPayments);

cout << "Total Pay Back: $"  << fixed << totalPayBack << endl;
};
```

The output that I should be getting for this code:

Loan Amount: $50000.00
Annual Interest Rate: 0.06250
Years to repay: 10
Monthly Payment: $561.40
Total Pay Back: $67368.06

The current output of this code :

Loan Amount: $50000.000000
Annual Interest Rate: $0.062500
Total Years to Repay: $10.000000
Monthly Payment: $0.062500
Total Pay Back: $-599859.388428

Comment: You should not divide the interest rate by 100. (The example corresponds to 7.5%, but you make it 0.075%.)

Comment: A yearly interest rate of X% is less than a monthly interest rate of (x / 12)%.

Comment: @idclev463035818: There's no integer division with `annualInterestRate /12 /100` as it's grouped as `(annualInterestRate /12) /100`.

Comment: On my original program, I have monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Batsheba yes, my fault

Comment: can you please show the current output of your code? it might help to track the calculations here

Comment: The current output that I am getting for this code is:                                                            Loan Amount: $50000.000000                                                                                                                                               Annual Interest Rate: $0.062500                                         
Total Years to Repay: $10.000000                                         
Monthly Payment: $0.062500                                                                   
Total Pay Back: $-599859.388428

Comment: Please put the current output in the question body so newcomers to the question don't have to dig through comments.

Comment: i did, but i have to wait for reviewer approving

Comment: @walid yeah, that's the lament of us dudes in the sub-2000 club :( That's why I ask OP to edit it.

Comment: I just did ! JohnFilleau & walid

Comment: @randomp103 now you have it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your current problems are:

1. You don't output `monthlyPayments`. You output `annualInterestRate` where you should output `monthlyPayments`.
2. You're not using the correct equation for monthly payment. See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142686/218822).

For principal (capital), `c`, periodic (monthly) rate, `r`, and number of periods (months), `n`, your periodic payment (monthly payment), `p` is:

```
p = ( c * r * ((1 + r)^n) ) / ( ((1 + r)^n) - 1 )
```

`(1 + r)^n` is the power factor, which you have already calculated. So you can use that in your final calculation for an easier read.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to update these two lines :

```
  // Find the monthly payment.
  monthlyPayment= (loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate)/(1-pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, 
                   totalYearsToRepay));

  cout << "Monthly Payment: $" << fixed << annualInterestRate << endl;
```

to be

```
// Find the monthly payment.
double monthlyPayment= (loanAmount * (annualInterestRate / 12) * pow((1 + 
                        annualInterestRate / 12), (totalYearsToRepay * 12))) / (pow((1 
                        + annualInterestRate / 12), (totalYearsToRepay * 12)) - 1);

cout << "Monthly Payment: $" << monthlyPayment << endl;
```

to use the proper formula and the proper printing.

Comment: welcome, mate. you can accept the answer if it works fine with you ;)

Comment: how do I accept it? sorry I am new to this @walid barakat

Comment: you can take a look here, it have some tips about stack over flow also ^_^

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

and i just found this question, i guess it has more details about your question if you interested

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090173/mortgage-calculator-math-error?rq=1